# Why have created_at and updated_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Many programming frameworks will automatically populate 2 fields to a model / table / collection. In Rails the two fields are **created_at** and **updated_at**. The function of the fields is self-explanatory.

**created_at**

The timestamp when the record was first created in the database.

**updated_at**

The timestamp of the most recent change to any of the data stored in the table.

I am working on a Meteor project which does not come out of the box with these fields, and so added **createdAt** and **updatedAt** in my project.

Then I began thinking: under what circumstances would we need to know when a record is first created, isn't the last updated enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every table need those. If you don't have a clear use case, don't add those. Your database and application will take additional performance hit from calculating, storing and reading them, for nothing.

Answer (score 11):

- to be able to sort records by latest/oldest
- to be able to display information about the object (like `user asked 10 mins ago`)
- to be able to analyze data (for example to check at what time questions are being asked)
- it's super helpful when you want to track/debug/audit what's happening in our system

.. and more. Of course, it's possible that your record don't need it now, but it's always better to save this info, since you won't have a simple way to come up with it later if you don't save it now.

Comment: These are all use-cases for updated_at ... but none apply to created_at

Comment: hmm, not sure if I understand - how can you sort records by oldest/newest using `updated_at` and get info about when it was first created?  or do you plan to keep whole history of updates timestamps? Which, yes - might be a good idea in some cases and is necessary in others, but will  make queries/methods more complicated - so make sure avoiding having one small fields really worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a *lot* of situations where you'd want to know when something is first created.

Just taking stackoverflow as an example:

Knowing when a question was asked is important. If you asked this question two years ago and then edited it yesterday it is very different from your having asked it yesterday.

Knowing when a question was answered is important. Think of some of the badges. "Curious: Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record.". What if someone retags all my questions which triggers the `updated_at` to be set to today. I've then gone from asking questions on different days to them appearing to be answered on the same day.

Those are just two examples. The general answer is: whenever you want to know when an object first existed in your system you want `created_at`. Especially if you're then going to be updating that object.

Comment: What is missing in a simple updated_at is a change history ... only the most recent change is kept. So while created_at give you some additional info, there is still a large amount of data lost with this method.

Comment: Providing a change history is a much more complicated problem which isn't something you'd want provided out of the box with rails (typically). There are gems around that solve that problem though like https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail